# Changing an internal anchor tags css when the link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

I have a navigation bar which contains a list of a tags linking to certain parts of the page.

I was wondering if its possible through either **javascript** or **css** to change the opacity of the link when it has been clicked and the content is displaying, when the next list item has been clicked that would change to the active opacity and the old link would change back to normal.

here is a working test of the page and the navigation bar down the bottom: 
http://www.luvly.co.nz/space/process.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **js/process-slider.js** add this lines:

```
$('a.panel').click(function () {

    $('.selected').css('opacity','1'); /* this one - the normal state*/
    $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    current = $(this);

    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);
    $('.selected').css('opacity','0.5'); /* and this one - the clicked state*/      

    return false;
});
```

Note: change the 0.5 to any number you want (0 < x < 1).

Comment: @Zim84 that is the OP code, I just added the two lines ( as you can see ).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `:active` and `:hover` pseudo class like this

```
#Navigation a:active
{
    opacity: 0.9;
}
#Navigation a:hover 
{ 
    opacity:0.4
}
```

this is an example so put these classes as per your code.

Answer (score 0):

Through CSS, you can do something like this and just simply change the opacity values below to what you desire since you didn't mention any specific opacity setting as of yet...

```
#process-nav-bar .panel:active {
opacity: 0.5;
}

#process-nav-bar .panel:hover {
opacity: 0.4;
}

#process-nav-bar .panel {
opacity:0.3; 
}
```